# What are the popular test automation tools for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, automated-tests

I need a test automation tool for Silverlight. Basically, I need a tool that would simulate users accessing, clicking buttons etc. on a Silverlight UI.

A google search has turned up several promising leads:

1. WebAii
2. White
3. Selenium-Silverlight
4. NeoLoad

I need to know what the pros and cons of each of them are, and of any other suitable tools for this purpose.

I would prefer a open source tool but am not averse to a proprietary one if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one available in [SL4 for unit testing](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut)
It's quite handy if you do MVVM to write unit tests against your models

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into it. Do you have experience on it that you can share?

Comment: I've started using it this week, it would be very nice if it could be integrated in VS unit testing environment but unfortunately it's running in its own SL application